# Jquery Bind Click Not Working

Tags: jquery, click, bind

I have this code for a Dropdown menu:

```
var timeout    = 500;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function jsddm_open()
{  jsddm_canceltimer();
   jsddm_close();
   ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
}

function jsddm_close()
{  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

function jsddm_timer()
{  closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

function jsddm_canceltimer()
{  if(closetimer)
   {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
      closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#mainnavigation > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open)
   $('#mainnavigation > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer)});

document.onclick = jsddm_close;
```

and I want to modify it so the drop down will open on "Click", not on "Mouseover" and to close on "Mouseout". I've tried to use this:

```
$('#mainnavigation > li').bind('click', jsddm_open)
```

but it's not working.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Show your html with your "dropdown"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some HTML would help.

Apart from that, I think your function works but clicking the `<li>` also triggers `document.onclick = jsddm_close;`
So your menu opens and closes right away.

Try to get rid of the `document.onclick` line and see if it works better

You also need a `return false;` at the end of your `jsddm_open()` function

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
 $('#mainnavigation > li').click(function() {
        jsddm_open();
 });
```

Anyway I think you are missing the " () " behind the methods, but It might just be that the syntax is new to me..

Comment: Used this and it doesn't work. The weird thing is that I used an "alert('test')" after "jsddm_open()" and the alert works. "jsddm_open()" function doesn't...